# How to draw a UML package diagram properly?

Tags: uml

I'm trying to simulate my packages using the UML package diagram:

Package diagram:

[image]

I've one web app and two desktop apps whom use RPC to comunicate with remote components. Is this how to draw a package diagram

Comment: First off all - aviod generic names like "Components", they does not bring any value to a concrete case. Are B and C mentioned 2 desktop apps? With what remote component do they communicate? Is this communication unidirectional?WEB all does not communicate with other parts?

Comment: @Aleks, it's related to [this question on which you have answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23311293/which-uml-diagrams-may-i-need-to-conceptualize-background-desktop-apps/23312251?noredirect=1#comment35696660_23312251). B and C do not communicate, the web-app comunicates with B and C via the Database. And here, also, the B and C use these remote components. How would you name that package (component)? The web-app do not use the components package.

Comment: You should model DB to show the (indirect) communication between B, C and WebbAPP, and even add deployment (as commented on the other thread, a distributed app often needs deployment view). Regarding the components... What excatly do they do? WHY B und C use components, what info do they get? Are components an external system or part of this one?

Comment: @Aleks, these components are deployed in a server apps which are classes and represents the stored tables in the DB. But, modeling the DB is via Class Diagram, no?

Comment: Yes, modelling the DB details is with classes, but you still need a component DB to show debendendies and how B, C and WebApp use DB. If these components provide access do DB, you should maybe make a component DBAccess to encapsulate those. I will paste a component diagram how I understand it so far as an answer. Please check it out and tell me it it reflects the reality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, continuing are conversation from the comments, here goes the diagram:

[image]

Please take a carefull look and give me your feedback. Especially on the pink note with my questions.

As you can see, I used components instead of the packages in order to be able to eventually add a deployment diagram and assign the components to corresponding nodes. Although package diagram is also valid, it does not permit eays traceability to nodes of the desployment diagram.

Note the interface of the DBAccess component. In this case it indicates the RPC nature of the dependencies.

Furtner you can add on or more class diagrams for each component, modelling their internal structure. Be sure to respect the interface in this case and show classes with interface.

**UPDATE (after the 1st comment)**

Fixes:

- WebApp spaks directly to the DB
- B and C communicate via sockets. C is a socket server and B initiates the connection (client). Note that this is a plain unidirectional dependency. In case that both can open the connection, just draw another interface, as provided by B (symetrical situation).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer it's cleaner, the web-app accesses directly to the DB. So, is this componenent diagram can replace the package diagram? And, if I add the supposition that B and C communicates via `TCP Sockets`, how may I draw that fact, please?

Comment: An updated version comes in a second as an update to the answer.

Comment: Would you please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415122/designing-an-operation-using-uml-sequence-diagram ?