# designing an operation using uml sequence diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

How to design this operation using the UML sequence diagram?

Scenario:

The Tasks (Controler Task) adds one line on the database, the Computer (Controler Computer) gets in loop the full lines of the database and when it detects a new added line in DB (Entity Task), it gets the IP address and the port number of the server (Controler Server) from the database (Entity Server) and then sends the message.

Any brilliant suggestion, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sequence diagram models the sequence of messages exchanged between a set of objects. So, the first step here is to identify the participating objects. 

Questions:
1- Please explain the nature of the following elements: Controler Tas, Controler Computer, Entity Task, Controler Server, Entity Server. Are they class instances, Java components, PHP pages, etc, etc.
2- "when it detects a new added line" - how does he "detect" it?
3- Finally, please explain the nature of the communication between the elements: is it sync or async, SP calls or SQL queries, RPC calls, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Operation is behavioral feature. It has no behavior definition. If operation defined, it means, that there is usually a behavior defined in context of classifier (or specialized classifiers) which can be invoked by operation. Operation and behavior are usually connected. Operation plays role of specification of behavior and behavior is a method, how instance of classifier will behave. To define the behavior, use some of behavioral diagrams (Activity, StateMachine, Interaction ...)
Descrition that you provided mostly corresponds to Activity.